# How to simplify $x \coth(x) > 1$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I have the inequality $x \coth(x) > 1$ which is correct for real arguments $x>0$. However, Mathematica does not seem to realize this:

```
FullSimplify[x*Coth[x] > 1, x > 0]

(* x Coth[x] > 1 *)
```

I tested this with a fresh Kernel 11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016).

How can I tell Mathematica to simplify such expressions?

Comment: `Reduce[x Coth[x] > 1, x]`.  `Simplify` is not intended to solve inequalities.

Comment: This gives the right solution for `x`, but I don't think this can be applied within a larger expression. I guess my question was not clear, but ideally I;d like simplify to recognize such expressions.

Comment: Your question still doesn't seem to be clear. If `Reduce` doesn't work, don't expect `FullSimplify` does.  In such a case you can use  `Plot`,  `RegionPlot`, etc  to estimate correct ranges of `x`.

Comment: Alright, it seems I have to treat such expressions manually. I just stumbled upon a similar expression, which `Reduce` cannot handle: `Assuming[0 < x < 1, Reduce[x*Cot[x] <= 1, x]]`. It looks as if the trigonometric functions are difficult to treat – I'll resort to visual inspection then.

Comment: Your approach is not an appropriate way of using assumptions. This should work `Reduce[0 <= x <= 1 && x Cot[x] <= 1, x]`, however it doesn't.  There must be some kind of a bug, try e.g. `Reduce[0 <= x <= 1 && x Cot[x] <= 1, x, Complexes]`. This is in _Mathematica 10.3_.

Comment: It seems `Reduce` can't figure out that the values are strictly positive, but at least it can work out that the values are all on one side of the x-axis: `Reduce[Exists[x, 0 < x < 1, x*Cot[x] - 1 == 0]]` (giving `False`).

Comment: Interesting! Thanks @Artes for pointing out how to use assumptions with `Reduce`. I'm sure this will be useful in the future. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll except it, since it seems to be the best solution.

Comment: `FullSimplify[x*Coth[x] > 1, x > 0, 
 TransformationFunctions -> (Reduce[{#}, x, Reals] &)]`